# Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 8 elements

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am trying to create a `Dataframe` from web scraping the same webpage with different sections, but when trying to signify the columns, I get this error :

`"Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 8 elements"`

```
url='https://money.cnn.com/magazines/fortune/fortune500_archive/full/1955/1.html'

webcontent=urlopen(url)
html_page=webcontent.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
table=soup.select("table")[0]
rows= table.select('tr')

table_data=[]
for row in rows:
    td_tag=row.select('td')
    row_values=[value.string for value in td_tag]
    table_data.append(row_values)

data=pd.DataFrame(table_data[1:])
cols=[header.string for header in table.select('th')]
data.columns= cols


data.head()
```

Your help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe page content changed.
there are two issues:
1. in `table_data` the first item you want `['1', 'General Motors', '9,823.5', '806.0']` start at 7th 
2. and you only need last 4 items in  `[header.string for header in table.select('th')]` `['Rank', 'Company', None, None, 'Rank', 'Company', 'Rank', 'Company']`

```
data=pd.DataFrame(table_data[6:])
cols=[header.string for header in table.select('th')][-4:]
data.columns= cols
data.head()

Rank    Company Rank    Company
0   1   General Motors  9,823.5 806.0
1   2   Exxon Mobil 5,661.4 584.8
2   3   U.S. Steel  3,250.4 195.4
3   4   General Electric    2,959.1 212.6
4   5   Esmark  2,510.8 19.1
```

Comment: Thank you! This got my code to run! Do you mind explaining why you used [6:] and the [-4:]

Comment: @user13599115 add explanation